# why openwrt use "V=s" in command line

Tags: makefile, openwrt

Which is discribed in the openwrt wiki

To build the OpenWRT tarball

```
cd attitude_adjustment
make V=s
```

[http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/easy.build](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905162437/http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/easy.build#to_build_the_openwrt_tarball)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that the `V=s` option is meant to provide more verbose information for troubleshooting purposes when building the OpenWRT firmware. From the more detailed build instructions given in [HOWTO: OpenWrt Buildroot – Usage](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/build#troubleshooting):

> ### Troubleshooting
>
> First get more information on the problem using the make option "`make V=s`".

Answer (score 2):

I found this [info](https://openwrt.org/docs/techref/buildroot#warnings_errors_and_tracing):

> The parameter `V=x` specifies level of messages in the process of the
> build.
>
> V=99 and V=1 are now deprecated in favor of a new verbosity class
> system, though the old flags are still supported. You can set the V
> variable on the command line (or OPENWRT_VERBOSE in the environment)
> to one or more of the following characters:
>
> - s: stdout+stderr (equal to the old V=99)
> - c: commands (for build systems that suppress commands by default, e.g. kbuild, cmake)
> - w: warnings/errors only (equal to the old V=1)

So `make V=s` means to display messages of **stdout** and **stderr** in the process of the build.

Answer (score 0):

This overrides the setting of a make macro. Consider this very simple makefile:

```
BAR = bar
foo:
    @echo $(BAR)
```

Running it:

```
$ make
bar
```

And now using the override:

```
$ make BAR=bistro
bistro
```

Comment: Thanks, I found the usage in include/verbose.mk, it seems it's overrided to print more message. But the definition of "NO_TRACE_MAKE " makes me confused again, why "make V=ss"?

Comment: I don't have the time to download/search for the makefile. Either add it to your Q or post an URL.